# How to identify overlapping GeoJSON layers in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, identify

I have a Leaflet map containing overlapping GeoJSON layers. How can I identify all features at the location clicked?

See http://jsbin.com/zavuda/edit?html,js,output for a demo using Leaflet sample data.

Note that the Campus layer can be clicked when it's the top layer, and its attributes are shown via the layer's `onEachFeature` function.

[image]

Then use the toggle under the map to switch on the States layer, which overlaps the Campus layer. After this the Campus layer can no longer be clicked on.

[image]

Is it possible to run an "identify" query at the location clicked by the user, and return all intersecting features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is some built-in way of doing this that I'm not aware of, my rough approach would be to use something like [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) to do the following:

1. Keep a list of all layers that you want to query
2. Set a click handler on the map to get the lat-lng of a clicked point
3. Take the clicked point, and check each layer for a returned polygon
4. Collect any positive hits and return

Leaflet-pip example:

```
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(statesData);
var results = leafletPip.pointInLayer([-88, 38], gjLayer);
// results is an array of L.Polygon objects containing that point
```